# How to show the error text for devexpress spinedit using VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I'm having a problem to show the `error text` for `spinedit` when user have reached the quantity `Max.Value`.

I want it to be like this :

[image: Example of the error text]

Here is my asp.net code for `SpinEdit`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="spinEditQTY" runat="server" Number="0" Width="300px" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code behind for the `Max.Value`.

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 
spinEditQTY.MaxValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("Quantity").ToString
spinEditQTY.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Quantity").ToString
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

add this property to your spinEdit

```
settings.ShowModelErrors = true;
settings.properties.validationSettings.ErrorDisplay = = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
```

Comment: it seems there is no `ShowModelErrors` for my spinEdit, instead it has `ShowOutOfRangeWarning` . set it as `true`

Comment: That's great !!